# Is there any API or go programming logic to get capacity of node in a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, metrics, kubectl, minikube

Using kubectl describe nodes, i am able to get the capacity of resources(memory,cpu) of a node. I want to get the same via go client or kube API (if available). Can anyone help me out?
i am using minikube version: v1.7.2
kubectl version : 
Client :  GitVersion:"v1.16.3"
Server :  GitVersion:"v1.16.2"
I am using metric-server to access the kubernetes resource.
Expected result:
Capacity of resources should be accessible through go program or kube API

Comment: Did you find a way to describe a node using go lang ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any API call you could use to get `kubectl describe nodes` this is because this command is generating all the output.

`Kubectl` retrieves all relevant pods (every pod that isn't failed or succeeded) on a node and sums up all their resource definitions.

You can look into the code and find the function responsible for generating information about node [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/85f1205efa89008e6e94a92d66a9dd691cb59825/pkg/kubectl/describe/versioned/describe.go#L2807).

Same for collecting all requests and limits for pods, function is available [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/85f1205efa89008e6e94a92d66a9dd691cb59825/pkg/kubectl/describe/versioned/describe.go#L3241-L3263) and it's called `getPodsTotalRequestsAndLimits`

Lastly the function what puts all that together can be seen [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/85f1205efa89008e6e94a92d66a9dd691cb59825/pkg/kubectl/describe/versioned/describe.go#L3177).

There is a really nice article about [Kubernetes API: Allocatable Node Resources?](https://medium.com/@gorenje/kubernetes-api-allocatable-node-resources-6ea88f828f0) The author is doing exactly what you are asking for but using Python.

Answer (score -1):

Kubernetes Client libraries are the ones you need to look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/#officially-supported-kubernetes-client-libraries

```
The following client libraries are officially maintained by Kubernetes SIG API Machinery.

Language    Client Library
Go          github.com/kubernetes/client-go/    
Python      github.com/kubernetes-client/python/
Java        github.com/kubernetes-client/java   
dotnet      github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp 
JavaScript  github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript 
Haskell     github.com/kubernetes-client/haskell    


Community-maintained client libraries
The following Kubernetes API client libraries are provided and maintained by their authors, not the Kubernetes team.

Language                Client Library
Clojure                 github.com/yanatan16/clj-kubernetes-api
Go                      github.com/ericchiang/k8s
Java (OSGi)             bitbucket.org/amdatulabs/amdatu-kubernetes
Java (Fabric8, OSGi)    github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client
Lisp                    github.com/brendandburns/cl-k8s
Lisp                    github.com/xh4/cube
Node.js (TypeScript)    github.com/Goyoo/node-k8s-client
Node.js                 github.com/tenxcloud/node-kubernetes-client
Node.js                 github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client
Node.js                 github.com/ajpauwels/easy-k8s
Perl                    metacpan.org/pod/Net::Kubernetes
PHP                     github.com/maclof/kubernetes-client
PHP                     github.com/allansun/kubernetes-php-client
PHP                     github.com/travisghansen/kubernetes-client-php
Python                  github.com/eldarion-gondor/pykube
Python                  github.com/mnubo/kubernetes-py
Python                  github.com/tomplus/kubernetes_asyncio
Ruby                    github.com/Ch00k/kuber
Ruby                    github.com/abonas/kubeclient
Ruby                    github.com/kontena/k8s-client
Rust                    github.com/clux/kube-rs
Rust                    github.com/ynqa/kubernetes-rust
Scala                   github.com/doriordan/skuber
dotNet                  github.com/tonnyeremin/kubernetes_gen
DotNet (RestSharp)      github.com/masroorhasan/Kubernetes.DotNet
Elixir                  github.com/obmarg/kazan
Elixir                  github.com/coryodaniel/k8s
Haskell                 github.com/kubernetes-client/haskell
```